# Is it possible to formalize (higher) category theory as a one-sorted theory, just like we did with set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, category-theory, foundations, higher-category-theory

Set theory is typically formalized as a one-sorted theory without urelements.

**Is it possible to do the same with category theory or higher category theory, formalizing the whole affair as a theory with only one type of object?**

I know that this runs counter to what some feel is the philosophical spirit of category theory, but I'm still curious if it's possible anyway, just as an interesting logical puzzle.

---

> <sub>It seems tricky to me at first glance. A "category" has a "set"
>   of "objects" and another set of "morphisms." That's already four sorts
>   of thing - category, set, object, morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>However, it's possible to identify an "object" with the identity
>   morphism on that object. So, you could perhaps use this idea to bring
>   you down to only three sorts of thing - category, set, and
>   morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>Alternatively, you could say that "object" and "morphism" are
>   both types of the more fundamental n-morphism, and arrive at a
>   three-sorted theory of categories, sets, and n-morphisms.</sub>
>
> <sub>You could also try to formalize a "set" as a discrete category,
>   and bring you down to only two sorts of thing - category and
>   (n-)morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>If you go with n-morphisms, maybe you could try to identify every
>   n-morphism with the (n+1)-identity morphism on it, and see if that
>   simplifies things somehow.</sub>
>
> <sub>The above are some ideas that I had; I'm not even sure if they'd
>   work. But assuming they do, that still leaves you with only two things
>   - categories and morphisms - and I'm not sure if it's possible to go one step further and get it down to one thing. Thoughts?</sub>

Comment: _Any_ multi-sorted first-order theory can be reformulated as a single-sorted one, but that is essentially just a trick and is conceptually meaningless.

Comment: The problem, really, is that there is not even a commonly-accepted first-order theory, multi-sorted or otherwise, of the category of categories yet.

Comment: How can you reformulate a multi-sorted first-order theory as a single-sorted one?

Comment: It's a standard trick. We have to change the signature of the theory, of course. The idea is that the underlying set of the model in the new theory will be the disjoint union of the underlying sets of the model in the old theory.

Comment: And in this case, we don't even need disjoint unions, since the type of objects is already a subtype of the type of morphisms: see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the trick that Zhen Lin is talking about in the comments is the following one. (If I am mistaking, please point it out.)

Take $\alpha$ a cardinal. An $\alpha$-sorted theory $T$ on the first-order language $\mathcal L$ with sorts $(X_k)_{k\leq\alpha}$ can be viewed as a one-sorted theory $T^+$ on the first-order language $\mathcal L^+ = \mathcal L \cup \{ P_k : k \leq \alpha \}$ where the $P_k$ are symbols of arity 1 relations and where the sentences of $T^+$ are obtained by substituting "$\forall x:X_k$" with "$\forall x \, P_k(x) \to$" and "$\exists x:X_k$" with "$\exists x:X_k\, P_k(x) \wedge$" in the sentences of $T$.

For example, the 2-sorted theory 
$$ \forall e:\mathrm{Elts}, \, \exists s:\mathrm{Sets}, \, e\in S  $$
on the language $\{\in\}$ can be understood as the $1$-sorted theory
$$ \forall e , \, E(e) \to (\exists s, \, S(s) \wedge e \in S)$$
on the language $\{\in, E, S\}$. In either case, you're talking about sets and elements and the theory states that every element must be contained by a set.

---

Taking Zhen Lin's comment into account, what's above only holds for $\mathcal L$ without function symbols and does not assert that relations act on the wanted sorts. So, for every function symbol $f : X_{i_1}\times\dots\times X_{i_n} \to X_k$ in $\mathcal L$, add a new relation symbol $R_f$ of arity $n+1$ in $\mathcal L^+$. Then add to $T^+$ the following axioms :
$$ \forall x_1,\dots,x_n,y,z, \, (R_f(x_1,\dots,x_n,y) \wedge R_f(x_1,\dots,x_n,z)) \to y=z, $$
$$ \forall x_1,\dots,x_n,y, \, R_f(x_1,\dots,x_n,y) \to (P_{i_1}(x_1) \wedge \dots \wedge P_{i_n}(x_n) \wedge P_k(y)).$$ 
(The first axiom assures that $R_f$ is a graph of a partial function).

Then, for every relation symbol $R$ of arity $n$ of $\mathcal L$ with input in the sort $X_{i_1} \times \dots \times X_{i_n}$, add to $T^+$ the axiom :
$$ \forall x_1,\dots,x_n, \, R(x_1,\dots,x_n,y) \to (P_{i_1}(x_1) \wedge \dots \wedge P_{i_n}(x_n)).$$

(I dont treat constants of $\mathcal L$ in here : constant symbols are just function symbols of arity $0$.)

Of course, it remains to substitute "$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = y$" with "$R_f(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$" in sentences of $T$.

Comment: You should add the assumption that $\mathcal{L}$ only has relation symbols and no function symbols, or otherwise mention that in $\mathcal{L}^+$ we replace all function symbols by relation symbols. Either way, we have to add appropriate axioms asserting that the relation symbols have the appropriate "domains".

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay in accepting this answer. This makes me rethink my initial question a bit. The thing that I found interesting about ZFC isn't just that it's one-sorted, but also has only one binary relation $\in$. It's now clear that I ought to adjust my question to ask if it's possible to formalize category theory with a one-sorted theory and also only one binary relation symbol.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: You can axiomatize a category pretty easily with a single ternary predicate that's basically construed as "z is the composite of x and y". I've seen this treatment a couple of places. It also gives a nice way to approximate the notion of a higher category: drop the axiom that would give the uniqueness of composites and replace it with axioms that tell you composites are unique up to a congruence.