# Is it possible to formalize a "universe" of categories as a one-sorted first-order theory with one binary relation and no functions?

Tags: logic, set-theory, category-theory, foundations, higher-category-theory

This is a modification of [a question I asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469644/is-it-possible-to-formalize-higher-category-theory-as-a-one-sorted-theory-jus).

In that question, I hadn't placed any limits on the number of binary relations allowed, so my question had an affirmative answer, but a trivial and uninteresting one. This modification effectively changes the question by making it much less trivial, so this is not a duplicate post.

ZFC set theory is typically formalized as a one-sorted theory without urelements, and with a signature containing one primitive binary relation and no primitive functions.

**Is it possible to do the same with category theory or higher category theory, formalizing a universe of categories as a first-order theory with only one type of object, one binary relation, and no functions?**

To clarify: what I want is to formulate a first-order theory of an entire "universe" of categories, much like ZFC is a "universe" of sets - not a first-order theory in which the models are individual categories in general. This could be done in several ways: the universe could be a category itself, effectively formalizing Cat in an "Elementary Theory of the Category of Categories." Or, you could perhaps think of it as a theory of the 2-category of 1-categories, or something like that. (The discussion with user18921 in the comments made it clearer to me that there was some confusion on this point.)

If the above is impossible, then as a small concession, I'll allow a single binary function $\circ$ to denote composition, though it would be nice to see if it's possible even without that. I would expect that it is, much in the same way that $\cup$ and $\cap$ don't need to be defined explicitly as function symbols in the signature of ZFC. (You could also probably formalize $circ$ instead as a binary relation, just denoting that the composition of two functions exists.)

As before, I understand that this runs counter to what some feel is the philosophical spirit of category theory, but I'm still curious if it's possible anyway, just as an interesting logical puzzle.

My comments from before are repeated, as they still apply, and are now more pertinent that the trivial solution to the original question no longer applies:

> <sub>It seems tricky to me at first glance. A "category" has a "set"
>   of "objects" and another set of "morphisms." That's already four sorts
>   of thing - category, set, object, morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>However, it's possible to identify an "object" with the identity
>   morphism on that object. So, you could perhaps use this idea to bring
>   you down to only three sorts of thing - category, set, and
>   morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>Alternatively, you could say that "object" and "morphism" are
>   both types of the more fundamental n-morphism, and arrive at a
>   three-sorted theory of categories, sets, and n-morphisms.</sub>
>
> <sub>You could also try to formalize a "set" as a discrete category,
>   and bring you down to only two sorts of thing - category and
>   (n-)morphism.</sub>
>
> <sub>If you go with n-morphisms, maybe you could try to identify every
>   n-morphism with the (n+1)-identity morphism on it, and see if that
>   simplifies things somehow.</sub>
>
> <sub>The above are some ideas that I had; I'm not even sure if they'd
>   work. But assuming they do, that still leaves you with only two things
>   - categories and morphisms - and I'm not sure if it's possible to go one step further and get it down to one thing. Thoughts?</sub>

Comment: This might work (I haven't figured out the details though). Your only concept is that of an arrow. Write $\mathrm{com}(f,g,h)$ to mean that the composition of $f$ and $g$ is defined, and equals $h$. Or in the other words, that $f,g$ and $h$ form a commutative triangle. You should be able to rehash everything into this language.

Comment: user19821, that sounds like what I addressed here: "But assuming they do, that still leaves you with only two things - categories and morphisms - and I'm not sure if it's possible to go one step further and get it down to one thing."

Comment: So I had started off with a similar line of reasoning, but still couldn't figure out how to formalize a "category." A "category" has a "set" of "objects" and a "set" of "morphisms", so that's four types of thing. Identifying objects with identity morphisms is simple enough, but how do you ultimately treat "category," "set," and "morphism" as one thing? You now need at least two binary relations - $\circ$ and $\in$.

Comment: I think a logician would argue that the notions of "set" and "category" aren't presupposed by category theory, since these concepts do not feature in the object language. So if you accept this point of view (and I'm not saying you should, necessarily), then you're down to 1 concept. Granted, it would be interesting if we could purge the metalanguage of concepts other than that of a "category," but its not clear to me what this would look like.

Comment: After all, we'd presumably still need concepts like "string" and "formal system," so where do you draw the line? I'm not saying it can't be drawn; what I'm saying is, I don't know where to draw it.

Comment: user18921: category theory is typically formalized using ZFC, where a category is defined as a 2-tuple $(Ob,Mor)$, ignoring some uninteresting stuff about classes and all that. In that context, it's perfectly fine to define a category of two "sets," with the "set" of morphisms satisfying certain axioms. But how, in a formal treatment of category theory that builds entirely on first-order logic, does one handle this issue?

Comment: Sorry my category theory is rusty, what do you mean by a category of two sets?

Comment: That should have said to define a category *as* two sets, sorry, not a category "of" two sets.

Comment: Okay.  But if you want to do it as a first-order theory, then you can forget about models of that theory. The same way we can do ZFC theory without worrying about models of ZFC.

Comment: Right, that's the idea. There might be "non-standard models of category theory," but there's also some "standard" one...

Comment: I don't think the concept of non-standard models of category theory makes a lot of sense. When we talk about a non-standard model, we're usually referring to a model of a theory whose intended interpretation is $\mathbb{N}$, such as Robinson arithmetic, or Peano Arithmetic. Of course, each model of ZFC has a set $\omega$ which we'd like to think of as $\mathbb{N}$, so that's why it makes sense to speak of "a non-standard model of ZFC." We're really talking about a model of ZFC such that $\omega$ is non-standard.

Comment: This is doubly confusing because "non-standard model of set theory" has a second, [completely different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model) meaning. Anyway, the point is, since category theory can't interpret arithmetic, it doesn't make sense to speak of "non-standard models of category theory." On the other hand, a non-standard model of [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS), which is a categorial approach to set theory, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Wait, why couldn't category theory interpret arithmetic? You can formulate monoids in general as categories with one object, and since $\mathbb{N}$ is a monoid, you ought to be able to formulate $\mathbb{N}$ as a category.

Comment: Actually, the link you gave puts it better than that. ETCS defines Set by making reference to a "[natural numbers object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object)". Any first-order theory of categories certainly ought to be able to formalize Set in a way that meets those axioms, and hence it also ought to be able to formalize the natural numbers object - no?

Comment: Its certainly true that (the usual, first order formulation of) category theory, *together* with some axioms can interpret arithmetic. Just like its true that the theory of monoids + some axioms can interpret arithmetic. But the (usual, first-order) theory of categories without any additional axioms cannot, and neither can the theory of monoids. From an external point of view, the problem is that these theories have finite models. To interpret arithmetic, a theory really needs to have the property that its every model is infinite.

Comment: Does that make sense? Admittedly, its a fairly subtle issue.

Comment: OK, I think I may see the confusion. I'm trying to formalize a first-order theory of a "universe" of categories, just like ZFC is a "universe" of sets. I'm not trying to formalize a first-order theory in which the models are individual categories in general. (Now that I'm starting to understand the discrepancy, I'm trying to figure out how to word this better.) Does that change your answer at all?

Comment: Sorry, this thing accidentally tried to put this in "chat," not sure if that's what I have to do...

Comment: Hey no chat for me today, I really need to get some assignments in. If you're trying to formalize a first-order theory of a universe of categories, I think that's a great idea and I think [Lawvere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lawvere) was (is?) arguing for the same thing. In that case, yes, you will *certainly* be able to interpret arithmetic. I think you should edit the question to make clearer what you're looking for. Don't assume people have read the other question !!

Comment: Sorry about the chat thing, MSE put that in there. How would you recommend I word this to make it clearer? Does "first-order theory of the universe of categories" make sense? Maybe what I really want is a first-order theory of Cat, a so-called "elementary theory of the category of categories" (ETCC)?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good way of putting it. I've heard that the appropriate concept is not the class of all categories, nor the category of all categories, but rather the 2-category of all 1-categories. So you're probably looking for an axiomatization of the 2-category of all categories, just like ETCS axiomatizes the 1-category of all 0-categories.

Comment: Excellent way to put it! So yes, I'll reword it that way, thanks.

Comment: Good luck! I think you should make it sound less like a technical exercise (is it possible to??) and more like a genuine foundational exercise (has anyone managed to axiomatize the 2-category of all 1-categories?)

Comment: I don't get the motivation behind the question. Somehow it misses the whole point of category theory.

Comment: The motivation is to come to a better understanding of the difficulties in formalizing a first-order theory of the category of categories, and to understand exactly what distinguishes such a theory from set theory. I thought it a useful conceptual exercise to embrace materialism for just a second, for the sake of figuring out how such a theory might compare to ZFC.

Comment: The answer is surely no, but it's not obvious how to prove it. The reason why the universe of material set theory admits such an axiomatisation is because that is what material set theory _is_. By contrast, there is no tradition of thinking of categories as extensional collections of other categories.

Comment: Zhen Lin: I suspect as much as well, and that's precisely why I asked the question. If "one binary relation, no functions" is the minimalist signature that's the hallmark of set theory, what's the minimal signature needed to represent category theory? In a sense, I'm trying to figure out what category theory "is," on a very deep level, and how it differs from set theory. I do note, however, that the tradition of thinking of categories as extending other categories seems to be partly reflected in the whole n-category thing.

Comment: Yeah, I am in agreement with Zhen that the answer is probably no.  Set theory is defined in such a way that it permits such a simple foundation of axioms.  And I think this is part of the reason why sets find their way into all areas of math, whether explicit or implicit.

Comment: Another obvious motivation for first order treatment of category theory is to make questions about the theory semi-decidable and accessible to mechanized reasoning, and theorems accessible to proof verification systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the logical puzzle is "yes". For any finite signature $\Sigma$, there is a sentence $\chi$ in the language of a single binary relation such that models of $\Sigma$ are bi-interpretable with models of $\chi$ (Hodges, *Model Theory*, Theorem 5.5.1).

Comment: And moreover, the proof of this is quite cute and elementary.  Slightly modified from Hodges’ version, for concision: given a (possibly several-sorted) language $L$ with finite signature, first choose for each sort $S$ a natural number $\alpha(S) > 2$, and for each relation symbol $R$ a natural number $\beta(R) > 1$, all distinct.  (Assume functions are coded by relations.)  Now, given any $L$-structure $M$, produce a graph $G(M)$ as follows: for each element $x \in M_S$, add a vertex $v_x$, connected by one edge to a copy of $K_{\alpha(S)}$ — this “tags” it according to its sort. [cont’d]

Comment: And whenever a relation $R(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ holds, connect $v_{x_1},\ldots,v_{x_n}$ by an $n$-armed star with arms of length $\beta{R}$.  Now, three not-too-difficult claims to verify: (A) you can recover $M$ from $G(M)$, up to isomorphism; (B) you can axiomatise which graphs arise from $L$-structures in this way by a single sentence $\theta_L$ in the language of one binary relation; (C) a formula $\varphi(\vec x)$ of $L$ can be translated into a formula $\hat{\varphi}(\vec x)$ in one binary relation, such that $M \vDash \varphi(\vec x)$ exactly if $G(M) \vDash \hat{\varphi}(\vec v_x)$.

Comment: Yes, it is a cute proof. I think you may need to modify your construction a little so that you can recover the order of the $x_i$ from the star that represents $R(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: ah, thanks; yes, I tried to simplify it a little too far.  Try this: represent $R(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ by a star with arms of lengths $\beta(R)+1,\ldots, \beta(R)+n$ going to $v_{x_1}, \ldots$ respectively.  We can now recover the order of the arguments from the lengths; and using $\beta(R)+1 \geq 2$ for the shortest arm ensures that this doesn’t create any triangles, so we can still pick out the $K_n$ tags and hence recover the original carrier set of the structure.  I hope we’re good now?

Comment: Yes, I think it works fine with that modification. Thanks for posting the proof.